# wgrep for special multiline grep (pcregrep)

Tags: grep

`wgrep` works well for every line in context search like `grep -C 2`. It also works for grepmail, special grep-like program for mailboxes. You can edit each line of output.

How to force `pcregrep` with multiline request like `^[ \t]+-.*\n +CLOCK` to cooperate with `wgrep` correctly (with ability to edit each line, not only the first)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created such one-liner

```
f=filename(s).org; diff --unchanged-group-format='' <(grep -i -nH -e  [.]* ${f}) <(pcregrep -v -M -nH -e "^[ \t]+-.*\n +CLOCK" ${f})
```

which is used instead of grep command in `grep-mode`.

Comment: If this post resolves the problem, please accept your own answer so we can mark it as done.